# Iterating over rows of a dataframe, and assigning multiple calculated values to the rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df:

```
dict1 = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 4}
dict2 = {'A': 10, 'B': 20, 'C': 30, 'D': 40}
dict3 = {'A': 100, 'B': 200, 'C': 300, 'D': 400}
df = pd.DataFrame([dict1, dict2, dict3])
```

(I'm working from home, I can't copy paste the output here, sorry)

Now, I would like to 'enlarge' `df`, then assign calculated values to the new columns.

```
df[['new_col1', 'new_col2']] = None
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    # insert the calculated values for `new_col1` and `new_col2` here
```

I think I do need to iterate over the rows, as the calculation is based on the values of the rows. I can of course manually insert the values for each cell one by one using `.at`, but I have hundreds of thousands of rows, and `~20` calculated values to fill in. How can I do this?

I tried:

```
dictt = {'new_col1': 1, 'new_col2': 2}
df.iloc[0] = df.iloc[0].map(dictt)
```

But then if I check what `df.iloc[0]` is, its a row of `NaN`. I also tried:

```
df.iloc[0] = df.iloc[0].replace(dictt)
```

But that didn't do anything. Also, if there is a better/ more proper way to do operations like this, I'm all ears.

Comment: `# insert the calculated values for `new_col1` and `new_col2` here` - how are calculated values? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Why need iterating? Is possible avoid it for better performance?

Comment: To calculate `new_col1` and `new_col2` for each row, I take the values of `A` and `B`, and perform some heavy calculations that doesn't involve pandas at all. I just want to store the results back to `df`

Comment: @jezrael I thought I need to iterate, as I need to get the specific values in each row, and perform calculations outside of `df`. I only use `df` to store results. If there is a better way I would love to hear it.

Comment: Ok, so need apply function with input A, B and ouput is new columns `new_col1, new_col2` ?

Comment: @jezrael, actually I suppose yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have some heavy complicated function main bottleneck is in this function, not in pandas, here is solution how iterate in [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
def f(a, b):
    return pd.Series({'new_col1': 1 + a, 'new_col2': 2 + b})

df = df.join(df.apply(lambda x: f(x.A, x.B), axis=1))
print (df)
     A    B    C    D  new_col1  new_col2
0    1    2    3    4         2         4
1   10   20   30   40        11        22
2  100  200  300  400       101       202
```

Another idea:

```
def f(a, b):
    return (1 + a,  2 + b)

df[['col1','col2']] = df.apply(lambda x: f(x.A, x.B), axis=1, result_type='expand')
print (df)
     A    B    C    D  col1  col2
0    1    2    3    4     2     4
1   10   20   30   40    11    22
2  100  200  300  400   101   202
```

Comment: Hmm, @jezrael, I'm trying to follow your first solution. What you have written works, but when I apply it to my actual code, I get a `ValueError: Other Series must have a name`. Any ideas why?

Comment: @AyamGorengPedes - Can you try `pd.Series({'new_col1': 1 + a, 'new_col2': 2 + b}).rename('val')` ?

Comment: hmmh doesn't work. Though I can do `res = df.apply(lambda x: f(x.A, x.B), axis=1, result_type='expand')`, then `df = df.join(res)`.

Comment: @AyamGorengPedes - If use only `print (df.apply(lambda x: f(x.A, x.B), axis=1))` this working?

Comment: Well `df.apply(lambda x: f(x.A, x.B), axis=1)` works fine, its the `.join` that is giving me issues. Now `print (df.join(df.apply(lambda x: f(x.A, x.B), axis=1)))` gives me a different error, `ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified`, which is weird since the other approach (my 2nd comment) works fine (no overlapping oclumns).

Comment: @AyamGorengPedes - I think need `df = df.join(res.rename('col_name'))`